# Find limit as $t$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)=1$. Find $\lim_{t\to0}f(x_0+t)^\frac{1}{t}$.

I tried using the epsilon delta definitions but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: Did you try using the definition of differentiable? In other words that there is a real number $f'(x_0)$ such that $f(x_0 + t)\approx f(x_0) + tf'(x_0)$ for small $t$?

Comment: @Arthur that's also a good way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$f(x_0+t)^\frac{1}{t} =e^{\frac{\log(f(x_0+t))}{t}}=e^{\frac{\log(f(x_0+t))-\log f(x_0)}{t-0}}$$

then note that exponential is continuos and evaluate

$$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\log(f(x_0+t))-\log f(x_0)}{t-0}
$$

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco this is an hint indeed, I don't want to give the full answer, the asker must work on it!

Comment: I see and it is a pertinent hint. In my opinion (maybe I'm wrong), it should be a comment, not an answer. Anyway, I haven't downvoted your hint.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco A good hint is better than an answer when the asker is facing with a problem to solve and maybe with an homework.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I've just added some detail, but no more than that.

Comment: I think now it is an answer that everybody can understand. Well done! I withdraw my negative review and upvote your answer.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco In general I prefer give the minimum amount of information an then add while the asker try to solve and ask for further explanation. But usually meanwhile a full solution is given by someone else.

Comment: So I was trying it out, and I believe the answer is exp(f'(x_0)? Am I right?

Comment: @lukeskyrunner note that the limit $\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\log(f(x_0+t))-\log f(x_0)}{t-0}$ is by definition the derivative of $\log(f(x))$ at $x=x_0$. Can you conclude form here?